# OmniAuth Facebook Authentication Nickname returning "profile.php?id=.."

Tags: ruby, facebook, authentication, sinatra, omniauth

I'm using Sinatra and OmniAuth, trying to authenticate using Facebook. Everything seems to be working properly except for the nickname property. My auth hash is returning something for the nickname, but it is not the person's nickname. For what I'm trying to do, getting the person's nickname is very important. And I already checked my Facebook page to make sure that I have a nickname set, and I do. It should be returning "HeroicEric".

```
get '/auth/:name/callback' do
  auth = request.env["omniauth.auth"]
  user = User.first_or_create({ :uid => auth["uid"]}, { 
    :uid => auth["uid"], 
    :username => auth["user_info"]["nickname"],
    :name => auth["user_info"]["name"],
    :email => auth["user_info"]["email"]
  })

  session[:user_id] = user.id
  redirect '/user/' + user.id.to_s
end
```

The hash that is being returned looks like this:

```
"user_info"=>{
  "name"=>"Eric Kelly", 
  "urls"=>
    {
      "Facebook"=>"http://www.facebook.com/profile.php?id=550432081", 
      "Website"=>nil
    }, 
  "nickname"=>"profile.php?id=550432081", 
  "last_name"=>"Kelly", 
  "image"=>"http://graph.facebook.com/550432081/picture?type=square", 
  "first_name"=>"Eric", 
  "email"=>"heroiceric@gmail.com"
},
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code extracting data from facebook OAuth answer is in `oa-oauth-0.2.3/lib/omniauth/strategies/facebook.rb`

```
  def user_info
    {
      'nickname' => user_data["link"].split('/').last,
      'email' => (user_data["email"] if user_data["email"]),
      'first_name' => user_data["first_name"],
      'last_name' => user_data["last_name"],
      'name' => "#{user_data['first_name']} #{user_data['last_name']}",
      'image' => "http://graph.facebook.com/#{user_data['id']}/picture?type=square",
      'urls' => {
        'Facebook' => user_data["link"],
        'Website' => user_data["website"],
      }
    }
  end
```

As you see, `nickname` is just a rigth part of URL. I suggest fixing facebook adapter to get an actual nickname. Facebook returns `user_data` filled with

```
{ ... "name"=>"John", "first_name"=>"John", "last_name"=>"Smith",
"link"=>"http://www.facebook.com/ujifgc", "username"=>"ujifgc", ... }
```

So, the `username` field is what you want.

Comment: This sounds like a good approach. The same issue was found for [rstat.us](http://rstat.us). We now look for a username that contains profile.php and display a HAML template for the user to enter a new username.

Comment: This issue has been fixed with OmniAuth.